# Which error message is better when users entered a wrong password?

Tags: security, authentication, passwords

Is there any differences between the following two error messages from security point of view when users entered a wrong password?

> Wrong username or password.
>
> Wrong password.

For example, when you enter a wrong password on the `Gmail.com`, it will tell you "The username or password you entered is incorrect".

Is there any considerations for security reasons? I think the error message: "The password you entered is incorrect" is more clear to users, And, What's more, it's very easy to check whether a username is exists on the `Gmail.com`: just click "Can't access your account?" and enter the username. If the username doesn't exists, it will tell you.

Comment: I'm sure if you tried the "can't access your account" trick a few thousand times it'd soon be noticed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about general security practices and not about programming within the scope defined in the [help].

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The idea is to not give hackers extra information. If you say wrong password, you've told a hacker that they have a correct username, and vice-versa. Although what you've said is true, on some sites it is possible to determine if you've guessed a username via other means.

Comment: Please note that most websites still do in fact tell a hacker if they have a correct email/username on the registration page. Because of this, you should better tell the user whether the email/username is correct to provide a better UX.

Answer (score 29):

The easiest and most common phrase to use is:

"You have entered an invalid username or password"

The reasoning behind this is to prevent someone from trying to brute force your account by 'guessing' the password. If the attacker gets an error detailing the password is incorrect, then they could try different passwords until getting it right.

However, if you provide a generic message like the one above, the attacker doesn't know if the user, password or combination of both is correct or not.

Comment: Aren't there better ways to prevent 'guessing' the password? Limiting login attempts, using reCAPTCHA etc provide more user friendly means to mitigate these attacks. By 'user friendly', I mean better UX.

Comment: @SupremeDolphin - Yes, but its not worth the risk. One reason: people tend to use the same username and password on multiple sites. If attacker has learned that this is a valid username here, they might try it on a site that they have already compromised. Another reason: on sites that use email as username, its really best to give attackers no clue that they are getting warm. Too many email lists floating around. Third reason: don't enccourage hackers. If they gain no info from your site, they may move on to other sites. **EDIT** I just saw your answer re registration page. Good point,

Comment: Some website I went to took this message and it brought me to their customer support because I believed that my email address was deemed invalid while the fact was just that my password was wrong (but valid). Validation and verification are two different concepts.

Answer (score 8):

Just adding some extra information. OWASP guidelines give you recommendations about this issue

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html#authentication-and-error-messages

> An application should respond with a generic error message regardless
> of whether the user ID or password was incorrect. It should also give
> no indication to the status of an existing account.

Answer (score 5):

Well, from a different point of view, security-wise, the two messages aren't much different. At least for sites that allow registration. The hacker could always go to the registration page and try to register with the said details. Of course, your website, which was initially secured by ambiguity, will straight away shout "that username is taken!" or "that email is already registered!" and it'd look like at that point security is a myth.

Comment: This problem is mitigated by using email addresses as usernames and always sending an email after a registration attempt. That way the simple act of attempting to register doesn't divulge if an email address is in use.

Comment: @ChathanDriehuys this technique is simply trying to secure applications by being obscure. Not only does it go against UX conventions (communicating clearly with the user), but it would result in sending a lot of unnecessary emails. Mind you, some developers use paid subscription to send the emails, probably to avoid emails landing in spam or some other reason. Moreso, it is standard for emails to be sent upon successful registration in the form of confirmation or account activation emails, or simply as welcome messages. Sending a registration attempt email is confusing to say the least.

Comment: I agree with you that the UX is complicated by this process, but it is a fairly standard practice. For example, it's recommended by OWASP: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html#account-creation

Comment: @ChathanDriehuys It's true that it is widely used and recommended by OWASP. But that doesn't make it a good practice. Have you noticed the "big boys" are moving away from this practice? The likes of Google and Adobe have even taken it a notch higher. They require you to enter an email address to login. Only when the email is registered can you enter your password. Does this practice make their login process less secure?
There are better ways to prevent brute force guessing, such as limiting login attempts, using reCAPTCHA etc.

Comment: *"it would result in sending a lot of unnecessary emails"* Huh? At the end of the process you don't say whether it succeeded or not, you say that the next step is to check your email to confirm registration. Any site with a "Forgot Password" mechanism has EXACTLY the same problem, that anyone entering someone else's email will cause an email to be sent... I don't see any way to avoid that, until we have some alternative authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts you don't want an attacker to be able to guess the existence of an account. So you'll always return the generic error message so that an attacker cannot guess if this account exists or not.

In GMAIL context's, it's probably that gmail doesn't want people mining the existing email addresses to be used by spam robots.

Yourself can decide whether enforcing security is a need in your application, or if you can provide more user-friendly error messages.