# Forgot Password in windows form c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, forgot-password

In the code below: I want to warn a user when he/she tries to enter an email which is (is not) associated with the database. When I type something is not in my database, it says "Your record is not in our database". But when I enter a valid email it says: **input string was not in a correct format**
so this line code doesnt work: **smtpClient.Send(message);**

```
    string randomCode = "";
    public static string to;
    public ForgotPassword()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_EmailSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string from, pass, messagebody;
        #region Generating random code
        Random ran = new Random();
        string randText = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        int Length_randText = randText.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            randomCode += randText[ran.Next(Length_randText)];
        }
        #endregion

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        to = txt_Email.Text;
        from = "------";
        pass = "------";
        messagebody = "You have requested to reset your password. Enter this \"" + randomCode + "\" - code to change your password";
        message.To.Add(to);
        message.From = new MailAddress(from);
        message.Body = messagebody;
        message.Subject = "Password resetting request";
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, pass);
        try
        {
            using (DALC.GetConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select email from loginuser where email = '" + to + "'", DALC.con);
                object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (Convert.ToInt16(result)>0)
                {
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
                    MessageBox.Show("I have sent your resetting code to you email. Check your inbox :)", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your record is not in our database");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please read about SQL injection.

Comment: I don't see in your code a valid email for "from"

Comment: If you inspect the exception, you will have more details about the problem.

Comment: Digital3D let`s name it something@yahoo.com if I have it in my database, the messagae should be sent to that email, if not message box says record is not in the databse

Comment: You're getting the error because you're selecting an email from the database (`select email from loginuser …`) using `ExecuteScaler`, which _"Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query."_ - so that is returning a string, on which you then call `Convert.ToInt16`, which then throws the exception you are seeing. You could use `COUNT(*)` instead, but **you must parameterise your query** - see https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Basic debugging step after "that `result` is not what I expected" is to see what that result really *is*. Then you would have seen that you were converting an email address to Int16.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yeah I corrected it -count(email)

Answer (score 0):

You actually shouldn't do that, this is considered bad practice. A malicious user should never be able to guess a valid Email address (which in your case he would be able to).

You should only give the user an Email with a password-reset if he/she enters their Email address correctly. Even if the Email address is not in your database only a message without data-leakage should appear, i.e. "An Email to reset your password has been sent to your address".

The same issue should be applied to a login: If the login fails a user should only receive a message that doesn't distinguish from the name / password, something like "You have entered an invalid username or password".

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922130/which-error-message-is-better-when-users-entered-a-wrong-password) for more information.

Comment: let`s say you signed up with email and forgot your password, when you enter your valid email, my app sends a resetting code to your email. This code works If I replace this code "

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select email from loginuser where email = '" + to + "'", DALC.con);
                object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (Convert.ToInt16(result)>0)
                {
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
                    MessageBox.Show("I have sent your resetting code to you email. Check your inbox :)", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your record is not in our database");
                }

Comment: with only this one : smtpClient.Send(message);

Comment: @AlishSafarli that will be because you're not then calling Convert.ToInt16 on an email address!